# ERRO SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un error de SQLSTATE[HY093] error de parámetro pero no encuentro cual podría ser el error.

```
include_once 'model/conexion.php';
$nombre = $_POST["txtnombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["txtapellido"];
$celular = $_POST["txtcelular"];
$ciudad = $_POST["txtciudad"];

$sentencia = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente (nombre,apellido,celular,ciudad') VALUES (?,?,?);");
$resultado = $sentencia->execute([$nombre,$apellido,$celular,$ciudad]);
```

Comment: en el prepare le dices que recibirá 4 parametros pero le asignas 3  `VALUES (?,?,?)`, y en el ejecutar le pasas 4

Comment: Comentarte que lo solucione cambiando los ?,? por '$nombre','$apellido','$celular','$ciudad' ya que mas arriba les paso los valores, voy a probar si aumentando ese ? que me faltaba se soluciona.

Comment: @CristianRojas lo que has hecho (cambiar los ?,? por '$nombre','$apellido','$celular','$ciudad') crea un problema de seguridad grave (inyección SQL) y no debería utilizarse como solución.